# VPN through root server

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn

I want to get computer reachable from the Internet, but I don't have a public IP. It's because I am connected through my provider's NAT. Due I have a own server in the Internet, I want go through my server in the Internet and additionally forward a couple of ports to my network.

How can I handle this? I think VPN is the right way, but I don't know how this works. My server is running Debian and my computer is running Ubuntu. I would prefer if I could use a SSH connection.

[image: network scheme]

I hope you understand my although my bad English.

Comment: You're saying you have a computer at work that you want to directly connect to your home computer hidden behind NAT, and right now you can do it by hopping on a secondary computer and from there going to your home computer?

Comment: No, my computer (me) is at home and that MAN is the network of my provider. I want to connect my home computer (me) from the Internet, e.g. from my mobile phone...

Answer (score 0):

Have the system  behind the NAT use openVPN to connect to your system in the middle.

That can keep a network connection open all the time depending on how you configure it.  Read up on openvpn.  http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation.html

The you can use iptables to redirect traffic (say ssh on port whatever?) coming from the internet->MAN->"my server"

so you can ssh (port 2222)->MAN (redirects 2222 to port 22)->"my server" (port 22)

Then you can hop to any system in that network.

Comment: I think you are right, but this topic is quiet complex. The effort is not worth it. I have to find a more simple solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use SSH, then it's as easy as 1.2.3...

Simply set up a reverse SSH tunnel (and any others ports you want to forward) - script it or such in a shell script of your choice, so that if the connection goes down, it re-connects via a cronjob or such.

I would also suggest using ssh-agent so you don't have to enter any passwords (or passphrases when using this), if set up properly.

It's all in the man page and/or here too: http://openssh.org/faq.html (then there's google too).